# Glorp and Oracle: limiting query result

Tags: oracle, limit, smalltalk

I'm using Glorp in VisualWorks and with an Oracle database. Because Oracle does not know the LIMIT command, following query returns **all** the records of myTable for which the WHERE clause evaluates to true.

```
q := Glorp.SimpleQuery
       returningManyOf: MyTable
       where: [:each | each name = 'test']
       limit: 10.
q orderBy: [:each | each id descending].
results:= aGlorpSession execute: q.
```

How would I go to incorporate ROWNUM in this Glorp query?

//edit Generated SQL:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name
 FROM MyTable t1
 WHERE (t1.name= ?) ORDER BY t1.id DESC
```

Comment: The usual way to limit the number of rows in Oracle is select * from (select ... order by ...) where rownum < 10. Can you modify the query that is generated by Glorp?

Comment: Yes, should have mentioned I know how to do it in Oracle. I just don't know how to do it in Glorp.

Comment: Does Glorp use cursors in the background when working with Oracle, or does it actually pull all the results in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Smalltalk.Glorp.DatabasePlatform I added two empty methods #printPreLimitWrapper:on: and #printPostLimitWrapper:on: which I override in Smalltalk.Glorp.OraclePlatform:

```
printPreLimitWrapper: anInteger on: aCommand
    aCommand nextPutAll: ' SELECT * FROM ( '

printPostLimitWrapper: anInteger on: aCommand

    aCommand nextPutAll: ' ) WHERE ROWNUM <= '.
    anInteger printOn: aCommand.
    aCommand nextPutAll: ' '.
```

On Smalltalk.Glorp.SimpleQuery I added:

```
printPostLimitWrapperOn: aCommand
    self hasLimit ifFalse: [^self].
    self platform printPostLimitWrapper: self limit on: aCommand.

printPreLimitWrapperOn: aCommand
    self hasLimit ifFalse: [^self].
    self platform printPreLimitWrapper: self limit on: aCommand.
```

And on Smalltalk.Glorp.QuerySelectCommand I altered the following method:

```
printSQL
    query printPreLimitWrapperOn: self.
    stream nextPutAll: 'SELECT '.
    query printSelectFieldsOn: self.
    self findBoundExpressions.
    query printTablesOn: self.
    query printWhereClauseOn: self.
    query printJoinsOn: self.
    query printOrderingOn: self.
    query printGroupByOn: self.
    query printPostLimitOn: self.
    query printOffsetOn: self.
    query printPostLimitWrapperOn: self.
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you *can* add ROWNUM to this query you may still not get the results you want.  The problem is that the WHERE clause is applied before the ORDER BY - thus, by limiting to the first 10 rows returned you'll get those ten rows, and then they'll be sorted.  Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE order_test(seq_num  NUMBER);

INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(20);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(19);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(18);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(17);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(16);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(15);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(14);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(13);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(12);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(11);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(10);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(09);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(08);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(07);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(06);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(05);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(04);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(03);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(02);
INSERT INTO order_test(seq_num) VALUES(01);

SELECT * FROM order_test WHERE ROWNUM < 10 ORDER BY seq_num;
```

The query returns

```
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

on my system.  I suspect that what you want is the equivalent of

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM ORDER_TEST ORDER BY SEQ_NUM)
  WHERE ROWNUM < 10
```

which returns 1 through 9.

I don't know if or how you can nest queries in Glorp.  (FWIW - I know and love Smalltalk, but I detest persistence frameworks for reasons such as this).  YMMV, obviously.

(BTW - thinking about this for a minute, you might be able to modify the #limit: method on Glorp.SimpleQuery to inject a comparison to ROWNUM into the WHERE clause - but as I said above, the results may still not be what's intended.  An implementation is left as an exercise to the interested reader :-).

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd suggest different syntax as
   Glorp.Query read: ...
You don't really want to specify the SimpleQuery class up front, and read: is much shorter than returningManyOf: and accomplishes the same thing.

I don't have the software in front of me at the moment, but I'm pretty sure that on Oracle the limit: command should translate into using rownum. What SQL are you seeing this generate?

Comment: OK, I will use read:. Writing the limit is delegated to the database platform. The default implementation is empty, and it is only implemented for PostgreSQLPlatform and SQLServerPlatform. I added the generated SQL to the original question.